# "ssl.SSLError: ... No shared cipher" when trying to handle HTTPS requests webserver

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, https, webserver

I'm trying to extend a web server I made to handle HTTPS requests via SSL.
My prof said we should use `ssl.wrap_socket` and gave us the cipher to use.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from socket import *
import ssl

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverPort = 443
serverSocket.bind(("", serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    print ('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

    connectionSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(connectionSocket,
                                keyfile="./server.key",
                                certfile="./server.pem",
                                server_side=True,
                                cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,
                                ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23,
                                ca_certs=None,
                                do_handshake_on_connect=True,
                                suppress_ragged_eofs=True,
                                ciphers="AES128-SHA256")

    try:
        message =  (connectionSocket.recv(1024)).decode('utf-8')
        filename = message.split()[1]

        f = open(filename[1:],'rb')
        outputdata = f.read()
        f.close()

        connectionSocket.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n')
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata)
        connectionSocket.send(b'\r\n')

        connectionSocket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
        connectionSocket.close()

    except IOError:
        connectionSocket.send(b'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n')
        connectionSocket.send(b'<html><head></head><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1></body></html>\r\n')

        connectionSocket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
        connectionSocket.close()

serverSocket.close()
```

I've tested this in the command line with the following code and it seems to work. It shows me the right info about the SSL sessions such as protocol, cipher, session-ID, Master-key and the contents of `index.html`:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
GET /index.html
```

For the next section of the assignment I have to put `"https://localhost:443/index.html"` into my browser, but my webserver crashes with this error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:661)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Maybe you could check your certificate/CA, or test server with some simple script that list some available ciphers: https://superuser.com/questions/109213/is-there-a-tool-that-can-test-what-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-of

Comment: @zhiqianghuang: "no shared cipher" has nothing to do with certificate validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>                             ciphers="AES128-SHA256")
> ```

According to [SSLLabs client tests](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html) AES128-SHA256 (called  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 in the standards) is not supported by major browsers like [Chrome](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Chrome&version=51&platform=Win%207&key=126) or [Firefox](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Firefox&version=49&platform=Win%207&key=135). Accepting only this single cipher on the server which is not supported by major clients makes that no common cipher can be found, i.e.

> ```
> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:661)
> ```

The fix is to accept more ciphers on the server to include ciphers supported by the browser. See [mozilla wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Modern_compatibility) for useful settings which can not only applied to major web servers but also your small server.