# No Shared Cipher on Server Side (SSL Package Python)

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, openssl

I am trying to connect my client to server using a custom cipher suit. (DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA)
This is the code on client side,

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as client_socket:
            # Wrap the socket with SSL/TLS
            ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
            ssl_context.set_ciphers("DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA")  # Set desired cipher suite
            domain = 'localhost'
            wrapped_socket = ssl_context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_hostname=domain)
            wrapped_socket.connect((domain, 12345))
```

This is on the server side,

```
server_address = ('localhost', 12345)  # Replace with the desired server address
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(server_address)
    server_socket.listen(1)

    while keep_running:
        server_log("Server is listening on {}:{}".format(*server_address), "success")
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        # Wrap the client socket with SSL/TLS
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
        ssl_context.set_ciphers("DEFAULT")  # Set a default cipher suite list
        wrapped_socket = ssl_context.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_side=True)
```

The server prints an error on the last line of the code, and the whole error code is,

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:1045)

I am using Python 3.7, and using TLS 1.2.

I tried to trace the packets using WireShark to see if I can get more info about this, unfortunately nothing useful came up. It only told me that about a "fatal" error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312959/ssl-sslerror-no-shared-cipher-when-trying-to-handle-https-requests-webser